# Laravel child relationship from the same table alias issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables structured as such:

**videos table**

```
id
```

**comments table**

```
id
commentable_id
commentable_type
text
```

And each has their own model.

Video has the following relationship to comment:

```php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
}
```

Here's where it get's a bit interesting though, because comments can have comments under them at 1 level, so a top level comment can contain any number of child replies but the children cannot have replies on them.

That is represented by the following relationship on the Comment model:

```php
public function replies()
{
    return $this->morphMany(__CLASS__, 'commentable');
}
```

#### The problem

I need to now sort these by a combined sum between the comment AND comment replies count.

I've tried adding a hasManyThrough relationship on the parent (Video) model but that ends up failing because the table isn't aliased (since there are technically comments through comments to get to replies).

How would I represent this relationship in laravel on the video model? What I've tried seems fruitless

#### SQL

I thought maybe writing out the SQL might help, but since Laravel doesn't seem to alias table names, it seems almost impossible to convert this into a provided laravel relationship

```sql
SELECT replies.*
FROM comments
  RIGHT JOIN comments AS `replies`
    ON `replies`.commentable_id = `comments`.id AND `replies`.commentable_type = 'comment'
WHERE `comments`.commentable_id = 'VIDEO ID'
  AND `comments`.commentable_type = 'video';
```

Comment: I think you can alias the table name in this way `rightJoin('comments as replies', 'replies.commentable_id', '=', 'comments.id')`. Just set the alias between the quotes.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ yes, but this way I believe we may lose the power of traditional laravel relationships, no?